# How do you increment the number returned from llength?

Tags: int, tcl

Suppose I capture the number of files in a directory using [`glob`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm) and [`llength`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/llength.htm):

```
# For this example, suppose llength returned 4.
set number_of_images [llength [glob -nocomplain -directory $destination_folder -type f *]]
```

I would like to use that number and increment it in a `foreach` loop depending on the number of files in another directory.

```
foreach file [glob -nocomplain -directory $source_folder -type f *] {
    puts [incr $number_of_images] 

    # I want to start the count at 5, and increment by 1 with each loop. incr fails to 
    # do so, as well as mathfunc::int.
}
```

My issue is, according to the documentation, `llength` returns a string:

> Treats list as a list and returns a decimal **string** giving the number
>   of elements in it.

Can I convert it to an `int` and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tcl, everything is a string.  Yes you can increment a variable that holds an integer (represented as a decimal string).

The issue is with your use of `incr`.  The `incr` command is used to increment a *variable* holding an integer, not an integer *value*.  Simply change your code from:

```
    puts [incr $number_of_images]
```

... to ...

```
    puts [incr number_of_images]
```

Comment: Technically, you can think of the string type as the supertype of all other value types (it's not implemented that way, but conversions are auto-inserted). This is quite different to other languages, but works well given the detailed semantics of operations in the execution model.